# How to remove site wide titles

Tags: html, .htaccess, title

I have a regular HTML/CSS website and a problem with my title. My site has arround 100 pages, half of them with normal title and other half with site name added to title... Format is something like this:

> My custom title - Site name

For this same page HTML title tag is like this:

```
<title>My custom title</title>
```

I have no idea where is this comming from: - Site name

I really dont know why it is appearing only on half of my sites but i really want to get rid of it.

What could be reasons for this?

**UPDATE**

This title only apears in Google search results and not in browsers. When i check source code with browser the title is normal, also title is normal in browser tab.

The wierd thing is that i dont know how exactly google choose to format this extension to my title. My domain has 3 keywords:

> www.key1-key2-key3.com

and on homepage title is like this:

```
key2 key3 • key1 key2
```

and google choose to modyfy title in SOME of my subpages like this:

change from:

> My site title

to:

> My site title - key2 key3

Why only some keywords from my homepage? how did google know that this combination will make sense at all. luckely the combination does make sense, but i really dont get why this is happening....

Comment: maybe there's javascript that changes the title. can you give url for a page that has the problem?

Comment: http://www.auto-karta-hrvatske.com/slike-hrvatske.html

in html and browsers title is normal but in google search results it also has site name

Comment: What you describe in your comment is probably something related to Google itself. Is there an example of discrepancy between the original HTML `<title>` element and the actual title that you see in the browser window (as this is what the original question implies)?

Comment: if it's google search results titles you don't like, there is no reliable method for changing them. You can read google's documentation here: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35624
It says you can change the title or the meta descpription for a page, but google algorithms decide what title to use, and you cannot tell google to change the title it shows.

Comment: the title tag is the same on my pc and wen i check source code with the browser. i had no idea google modifies titles like this, im into SEO but i hear it first time